# How do I complete this function len for the length of a line segment?

Tags: string-manipulation

I need to have `len[{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}]` is `Sqrt[(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2]`. The beginning of the function will be defined as `len[lineseg_]:=(((lineseg[[1,1]]-lineseg[[2,1]])^2)+`
I don't know how to finish the function.

Comment: `EuclideanDistance @@ lineseg`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the *built-in* function [`Norm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html?q=EuclideanDistance) or [`EuclideanDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EuclideanDistance.html?q=EuclideanDistance)

```
Norm[{x1, y1} - {x2, y2}]
```

$\sqrt{|x1 - x2|^2 + |y1 - y2|^2}$

```
EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to measure multiple line segments you can apply your function or in-built functions to list. You can also use `RegionMeasure` (1 dimension) or `ArcLength` for `Line`.

Consider the polygon:

```
pol={{1.00375, -0.0754931}, {0.657009, 0.393524}, {0.184008, 
  1.06061}, {-0.116952, 1.13466}, {-0.990624, 
  0.456674}, {-1.10291, -0.0266122}, {-0.634718, -0.605872}, \
{-0.476277, -0.829135}, {0.191155, -0.954093}, {0.720451, -0.666725}}
```

[image]

If you wanted to calculate perimeter (sum of lengths of line segments):

```
nm = Norm[#1 - #2] & @@@ Partition[pol, 2, 1, 1];
ed = EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[pol, 2, 1, 1];
Total@nm
Total@ed
RegionMeasure[Line[Join[pol, {pol[[1]]}]], 1]
ArcLength[Line[Join[pol, {pol[[1]]}]]]
```

All yield: 6.2685

You could use your own function if you wanted.